# Spring-data-redis create cluster for RedisCacheManager

Tags: spring-data-redis

Hi，I try to create rediscluster for RedisCacheManager,but the properties of cluster not work. 
Error info like this:
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool

Example:
RedisClusterConfig.class

```
@Configuration
public class RedisClusterConfig {
    @Bean
    RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration(){
        List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        nodes.add("192.168.145.141:7001");nodes.add("192.168.145.141:7002");nodes.add("192.168.145.141:7003");
        nodes.add("192.168.145.141:7004");nodes.add("192.168.145.141:7005");nodes.add("192.168.145.141:7006");
        RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration(nodes);
        return redisClusterConfiguration;
    }
    @Bean("redisConnectionFactory")
    JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(){
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration());
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }
    @Bean("redisCacheManager")
    public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager() {
        return RedisCacheManager.create(redisConnectionFactory());
    }
}
```

DemoApplication.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
   }
   @Bean
   public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
      return args -> {
         System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
         String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
         Arrays.sort(beanNames);
         for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
         }
         RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = (RedisConnectionFactory)ctx.getBean("redisConnectionFactory");
         RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = (RedisCacheManager)ctx.getBean("redisCacheManager");
         Cache cache = redisCacheManager.getCache("abc");
         if(cache != null){
            cache.put("13",13);
            String a = cache.get("13").toString();
            System.out.println("a is " + a);
         }else {
            System.out.println("can not find cache");
         }
      };
   }
}
```

I debug the code ,find like this:

Debug info :
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YGz2.png)

I do not know why the clusternodes unequle cache nodes. 
Pom file like this:

Comment: <dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>redis.clients</groupId><artifactId>jedis</artifactId><version>2.9.0</version></dependency>